# Storage encrypted data RSA in MySQL

Tags: mysql, storage, rsa

I'm developing a web app and I have to encrypt data with RSA. I'm using FuelPHP and MySQL.
My problem is that when I want to insert encrypted value, it doesn't works, the value is null.

For example, when I want to insert

`"Š@žÊ~±ðÞ” ¯šÝ²à6°ÔökáÒïX´nÜ t|÷"ŒIñˆÃæ\{·"/8QzÑ6©Õîýízâ®ï Û»·Åe“ópÓ*ˆeÍ,¸XK’‡HR")DO@þÞœ¬±1õ0ð>‚ûÜÑ ;´šSxÐ‘Óýäƒ6ÈJ"`

which is `Guillaume` encrypted with an RSA private key.
The inserted value is null.

The type of my attribute is varchar(128), I also tried varchar(256) but it doesn't works.

Comment: Do you wants to store it from command prompt? I don't think you can do   so btw read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283197/1673391)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Binary data type such as BLOB for storing this kind of data.